# Can't get images into node red dashboard from windows

Tags: image, dashboard, node-red

I'm trying to upload an image into an html template node in node red, I'v changed httpStatic to:

```
httpStatic: 'C:\\images',
```

and uncommented:

```
httpAdminRoot: '/admin',
```

in settings.js file and I restarted Node Red but it didn't work, knowing that I tried different pathes to my image. Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong ?!

This is my testing flow

```
[{"id":"d41e6e2e.32de3","type":"function","z":"7e315e54.b418c","name":"Convert info to image","func":"\nreturn msg","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":410.0173645019531,"y":305.3264021873474,"wires":[["4707d1b7.c63c2","d8509296.ba789"]]},{"id":"4707d1b7.c63c2","type":"ui_template","z":"7e315e54.b418c","group":"e1c5a186.41af2","name":" HTML Template","order":3,"width":"3","height":"3","format":"<p><img style=\"display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;\" src={{msg.payload}} width=\"128\" height=\"128\"/></p>","storeOutMessages":true,"fwdInMessages":true,"templateScope":"local","x":804.0173492431641,"y":306.3264021873474,"wires":[[]]},{"id":"d8509296.ba789","type":"debug","z":"7e315e54.b418c","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"false","x":851.0972442626953,"y":207.00000715255737,"wires":[]},{"id":"dfbc3481.f6b438","type":"inject","z":"7e315e54.b418c","name":"","topic":"","payload":"/n.jpg","payloadType":"str","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":true,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":199.1006622314453,"y":228.40625715255737,"wires":[["d41e6e2e.32de3"]]},{"id":"e1c5a186.41af2","type":"ui_group","z":"","name":"Lamp","tab":"18f3acca.3bcee3","order":1,"disp":true,"width":"6","collapse":false},{"id":"18f3acca.3bcee3","type":"ui_tab","z":"","name":"Field","icon":"dashboard","order":1,"disabled":false,"hidden":false}]
```

And this is the error I'm having on the browser [image]

Comment: Which `settings.js` did you edit? Also there is no need to move the admin root to just server up static content

Comment: I editted the file located in the node red folder :C:\Users\alma\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-red\settings.js

Comment: I commented back the admin root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have edited the wrong copy of `settings.js`. The copy in the install directory (which you edited) is used as the default and copied to the `userDir` the first time Node-RED is run.

The version of `settings.js` that you are actually using is output to the log at start up, but it will most likely be in the following directory:

```
c:\Users\alma\.node-red
```

Comment: I can't find a folder like that ! in the other hand there are a lot of settings.js files in the folder I told you about

Comment: It was actually in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin\.node-red, Thank you very much!

Comment: I dread to think what you've done to end up with your Java install location to be your Node-RED `userDir`